# How to make NSNumber accept optionals

Tags: swift, core-data

Can anyone make this code better? My problem here is that I want "`protein`, `kh` and `fat`" be `optionals`. But `NSNumber` will not accept optionals as parameters. So I have to do this really ugly stuff. Is there a better way?

```
@IBAction func save(){
    if nameLabel.text.isEmpty {
        Toast.showToast("Name cannot be empty.", view: view)
    } else {
        let kcal = kcalLabel.text.toInt()
        let protein = proteinLabel.text.toDouble() // returns Double?
        let kh = khLabel.text.toDouble() // returns Double?
        let fat = fatLabel.text.toDouble() // returns Double?
        foodItem.name = nameLabel.text
        foodItem.kcal = kcal == nil ? nil : NSNumber(integer: kcal!)
        foodItem.protein = protein == nil ? nil : NSNumber(double: protein!)
        foodItem.kh = kh == nil ? nil : NSNumber(double: kh!)
        foodItem.fat = fat == nil ? nil : NSNumber(double: fat!)
        foodItem.remarks = remarksLabel.text
        foodItem.requireUpdate = NSNumber(bool: true)
        foodItem.isdeleted = NSNumber(bool: false)
        delegate.addFoodItemViewController(self, didAddFoodItem: foodItem)
        Toast.showToast("FoodItem saved.", view: view)
    }
}
```

Here is the model:

```
class FoodItem: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var kcal: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var kh: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var protein: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var fat: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var remarks: String?
    @NSManaged var isdeleted: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var requireUpdate: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var displayOrder: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var uid: String?

}
```

Comment: NSNumber is objC type while optionals are presented in Swift and dont work with objC ... cant u just convert NSNumber to Double for example and optionally unwrap values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a couple extension methods to clean up the syntax a bit:

```
extension Int {
    func toNSNumber() -> NSNumber {
        return NSNumber(integer: self)
    }
}

extension Double {
    func toNSNumber() -> NSNumber {
        return NSNumber(double: self)
    }
}
```

Then:

```
foodItem.kcal = kcal?.toNSNumber()
foodItem.protein = protein?.toNSNumber()
```